# Why does adding the same number to epoch times for different dates return the same date for both?

Tags: perl

Given these epoch times:

- 1425801600 (2015-03-08)
- 1425884400 (2015-03-09)

Adding 613 days (613*24*3600 seconds) gives:

- 1478764800 (2016-11-10)
- 1478847600 (2016-11-10)

How is this possible?

Comment: The two timestamps are NOT 24 hours (86400 seconds) apart, and DST changes reduce the difference further, placing both result times in the same day.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, That's incorrect. Being a factor or 86400 seconds apart is no worse than being exactly 86400 seconds apart. The problem is entirely the DST change, as I answered an hour before your made your comment.

Answer (score 9):

In UTC, all days have 24 hours, so the problem doesn't exhibit itself when using that time zone.

```
$ TZ=Etc/UTC date --date=@1425884400 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2015-03-09 07:00:00

$ TZ=Etc/UTC date --date=@1478847600 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2016-11-11 07:00:00
```

But you weren't using UTC. Because of DST changes, not all days have 24 hours in many time zones. For example, Nov 6th of 2016 was 25 hours long in America/Los_Angeles, so 1478847600 is an hour short of 613 days later than 1425884400 in that time zone.

```
$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date --date=@1425884400 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2015-03-09 00:00:00

$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date --date=@1478847600 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2016-11-10 23:00:00
```

Using a module such as a DateTime avoids these problems.

```
$ perl -e'
   use DateTime qw( );
   my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(
      epoch => 1425884400,
      time_zone => "America/Los_Angeles",  # Often "local"
   );
   CORE::say( $dt );
   $dt->add( days => 613 );
   CORE::say( $dt );
   CORE::say( $dt->epoch );
'
2015-03-09T00:00:00
2016-11-11T00:00:00
1478851200               # Not 1478847600!
```